# What is the cleanest way to have selenium read through multiple search terms from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a text file that reads like this:

```
Search Term 1
Search Term 2
Search Term 3
...
```

So far I've coded a script that takes the first line of the text file and searches it successfully:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/p1/Environments/p1_env/chromedriver")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
m = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m.clear()
        m.send_keys(line)
        time.sleep(0.1)  
        m.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.quit
```

What is the most condensed way to have the script run through the entire list in my text file?

My ultimate objective is to have selenium search each term, then output whether or not a specific search result exists. This question is just a piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you asking for correctly, the answer is:
You don't need to `driver.get("https://www.google.com/")` for each search string iteration. You need to open Google only once, then to clear the previous search string, insert a new search string and get the new search results.
Something like this:

```py
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
m = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        m.clear()
        m.send_keys(line)
        time.sleep(0.1)  
        m.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(5)
        #read the search results etc...
```

Comment: Not quite. I want the script to perform a search for each Search Term from the text doc. At the moment the script only performs one search for Search Term 1.

I feel like I'd need to use range(i)?

Comment: In case your text file will contain one search term per line by `for line in file:` you will get the search terms one by one per iteration. As I wrote

Comment: My apologies as I have very basic experience with Python. I will explain what I mean is a procedural format
1. Read txt file
2. Search Google for each line from the txt file -- At the moment that script online reads the first line and searches for it. How do I repeat this task for the other lines below?

Comment: OK, this is what I'm trying to do here. I'm reading the text file and per each iteration i.e. per each text line of the text file content I'm performing the search for the accepted text from the file i.e the search term. I don't understand what's wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure either. When I run your edit, I'm still performing a search for only the 1st Search term, rather than all of them. I do see two of the same errors - DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead

Comment: Do you mean your code performs only the first search? And what happens after that? Why don't it continue? Do you perform `driver.quit` at the and of the iteration inside the `for`  loop?

Comment: I don't have a for loop in my script. Where would I put it?

Comment: I my answer! I see you never try it...

Comment: This is not readable...

Comment: I have just added the entire script to the question

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you clearly or you me. Please see the delay I added inside the loop. Let me know if now it behaves differently?

Comment: No luck, opens up one Chrome window and only searches the first term still